# Flutter: I need a hand with dart obj and mapping

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm kind of starting out with Dart and Flutter. I already got a bit the hang of it. But one thing is blocking me. And it's confusing my mind a little.

Take this gist in consideration https://gist.github.com/MichelDiz/9af4e74f2a8c83cdb592257678e1cf71

The issue is, I need to create widgets based on JSON which is in the gist. This JSON is a little different from the "common" ones (So I couldn't find similar examples on the internet). It is a tree of objects and not maps. However, I need to map to create widgets dynamically. And seems like the class doesn't fit right. And I don't have much experience creating complex classes for JSON files.

I've used https://app.quicktype.io/ to create the basics class.

So this code below is my blocking:

```
  return Center(
      child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      ...(resp.groups as List<Group>).map((group) {
        //print(group);
        return  GroupBody();
      })//.toList()
      // GroupBody(),
      // GroupBody(),
    ],
  ));
```

And the error

```
flutter: The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<StateResponse>(dirty, state:
flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState<StateResponse, AsyncSnapshot<StateResponse>>#21e11):
```

This is the main error tho

```
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Group>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
```

I am only creating a bunch of cards for each 'group' and each 'zero'. In the JSON I have 6 Groups and 3 Zeros. So 6 group cards and 3 Zero Cards.

That's all.

Cheers. And thank you for minding.

PS. Also if I cut off the code and put just `(data.groups as List).map((group) => print(group));` the error still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
children: <Widget>[
      ...(resp.groups as List<Group>).map((group) {
        //print(group);
        return  GroupBody();
      })
```

You could do something like this:

```
children: resp.groups.values.map((group) {
        //print(group);
        return  GroupBody();
      }).toList()
```

Where `group` is a map and you can access to it like this:

```
group['members']['1']
```

Comment: No way, `The argument type 'MapEntry<?, ?> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic> Function(String, Group)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

Comment: I updated my answer. You could iterate through the list of values of resp.groups.

Comment: Thanks! this is it! this "values" made the whole difference. There are some docs on it?

Comment: You could check the values property of the Map class here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Map-class.html